# Responsive iframe in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe

Apologies for the very simple question! I am embedding a YouTube video on my WordPress site and want to make it responsive, is there a simple way I can add some code to the html - this is what I have at the moment:

```
<center><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zmRoFi5HCAc?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>
```

Comment: Where is your code? Are you using a CSS framework? Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: `<center>` tags are deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 3):

I think WordPress added new theme support for this (wp 5.x):

```
// Add support for responsive embeds.
add_theme_support( 'responsive-embeds' );
```

Reference: [Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/themes/theme-support/#responsive-embedded-content)

Answer (score 1):

In your theme's CSS or custom CSS section add this style:

```
iframe{
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

This should make your iframe based video embeds, mobile responsive. Let me know if it worked or not? Also you may share your link please if it does not work.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your help - I just added the custom CSS and it worked :)

Comment: @Alzad glad it worked! You may mark this my response as Chosen Answer :)

Comment: I did but apparently my marks will only appear after a certain amount of time as I am new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Alzad no problem! Welcome to Stack Overflow Alzad!

Answer (score 1):

This [CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) explains how to do this well.

I put some explanatory comments in the following snippet for you.

```css
.responsive-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* fallback if calc() not supported */
    padding-bottom: calc(315 / 560 * 100%); /* aspect ratio of iframe */
    height: 0; /* let padding set the height */
}

.responsive-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; /* fill container */
    height: 100%; /* fill container */
}

center {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: both;
}
```

```html
<center><div class="responsive-container"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zmRoFi5HCAc?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin called "Responsive Media". It makes embedded media (by oEmbed) like a Youtube video responsive. All you have to do (after installing this plugin) is just inserting the Youtube video URL in your article.

https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-media/